# Apex build hook - print output

Tags: apex

I have a bash script attached to build hook in project.json. 
The problem is that I do not get the output from that script print on the console when I do:

```
apex deploy
```

This is the bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

npm run-script flow
../../node_modules/.bin/webpack --config ../../webpack.config.js --bail
```

Is there a way to print the output from the hook scripts?

Thanks.

Comment: Whats that bash script contains, would you mind pasting that here ?

Comment: of course not, question updated.

Comment: actually the question is more general, can I get the output from any shell command I execute in the hook?

Comment: `../../node_modules/.bin/webpack --config ../../webpack.config.js --bail >> /tmp/log`
 try this

Comment: it could work, thanks. What I did however was running those commands in the script outside the hook and then I get the output, etc.